# Without push instructions

Tags: assembly, gcc, amd64

If I pass an argument to a function, it should be translated in assembly language into `push something`. I coded the following in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int a, int b,int c)
{
    int total;
    total = a + b + c;
    printf ("I will return now");
    return(total);
}

int media(int a, int b,int c)
{
    int total;
    total = (a + b + c)/3;
    printf ("\nI will return now\n");
    return (total);
}

int main ()
{
    int num1,num2,num3;
    char keypress[1];

    num1 = 5;
    num2 = 10;
    num3 = 15;
    printf ("\nCalling sum function\n");
    sum(num1,num2,num3);
    printf ("\nWaiting a keypress to call media function\n");
    scanf ("%c",keypress);
    media(num1,num2,num3);
    printf ("\nWaiting a keypress to end\n");
    scanf ("%c",keypress);
    return(0);
}
```

I compiled it: `gcc -S example.c`. It generated an `example.s` file and my expectation was to saw some push instructions. Here is the produced assembly code:

```
    .file   "example.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "I will return now"
    .text
    .globl  sum
    .type   sum, @function
sum:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $32, %rsp
    movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)
    movl    %esi, -24(%rbp)
    movl    %edx, -28(%rbp)
    movl    -24(%rbp), %eax
    movl    -20(%rbp), %edx
    addl    %eax, %edx
    movl    -28(%rbp), %eax
    addl    %edx, %eax
    movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   sum, .-sum
    .section    .rodata
.LC1:
    .string "\nI will return now"
    .text
    .globl  media
    .type   media, @function
media:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $32, %rsp
    movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)
    movl    %esi, -24(%rbp)
    movl    %edx, -28(%rbp)
    movl    -24(%rbp), %eax
    movl    -20(%rbp), %edx
    addl    %eax, %edx
    movl    -28(%rbp), %eax
    addl    %edx, %eax
    movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %ecx
    movl    $1431655766, %edx
    movl    %ecx, %eax
    imull   %edx
    movl    %ecx, %eax
    sarl    $31, %eax
    movl    %edx, %ecx
    subl    %eax, %ecx
    movl    %ecx, %eax
    movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
    movl    $.LC1, %edi
    call    puts
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size   media, .-media
    .section    .rodata
.LC2:
    .string "\nCalling sum function"
    .align 8
.LC3:
    .string "\nWaiting a keypress to call media function"
.LC4:
    .string "%c"
.LC5:
    .string "\nWaiting a keypress to end"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB2:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movl    $5, -4(%rbp)
    movl    $10, -8(%rbp)
    movl    $15, -12(%rbp)
    movl    $.LC2, %edi
    call    puts
    movl    -12(%rbp), %edx
    movl    -8(%rbp), %ecx
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %ecx, %esi
    movl    %eax, %edi
    call    sum
    movl    $.LC3, %edi
    call    puts
    leaq    -13(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rsi
    movl    $.LC4, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    __isoc99_scanf
    movl    -12(%rbp), %edx
    movl    -8(%rbp), %ecx
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %ecx, %esi
    movl    %eax, %edi
    call    media
    movl    $.LC5, %edi
    call    puts
    leaq    -13(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rsi
    movl    $.LC4, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    __isoc99_scanf
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE2:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Of course, I'm missing something because I just saw  two `pushq` instructions.

My question is what am I missing?

Comment: Answers below are accurate. Don't forget thought that  `push` is not always used when calling functions in 32 bits architecture. You'll probably see `mov DWORD PTR [ESP+0x8], 0x24`,  `mov DWORD PTR [ESP+0x4], 0xa` and `mov DWORD PTR [ESP], 0x5` more often.

Answer (score 6):

> if I pass an argument to an function it should be translated in
>   assembly language into push something

That's true for some 32-bit calling conventions, but your program is a 64-bit program and thus follows the [System V Application Binary Interface for AMD64](http://x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf).

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI:

> The calling convention of the System V AMD64 ABI is followed on
>   Solaris, Linux, FreeBSD, Mac OS X, and other UNIX-like or
>   POSIX-compliant operating systems. ***The first six integer or pointer
>   arguments are passed in registers*** RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX, R8, and R9,
>   while XMM0, XMM1, XMM2, XMM3, XMM4, XMM5, XMM6 and XMM7 are used for
>   floating point arguments. For system calls, R10 is used instead of
>   RCX.

Answer (score 1):

If you want assembly code without the use of push instruction from a C code, there is always the C prototype #inline.

Answer (score 0):

-I think you must read more about passing parameters using x86-64 and x32 modes.

-As @jason Geffner has said, injecting aguments via 32 bits is performed by stacking em up, while via 64 bits, is different, they are stored in regisers (notably rsi,rdi)

-This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28601414/calling-c-function-from-x64-assembly-with-registers-instead-of-stack) illustrates more the mechanism of printf arguments introducing in 64 bit processors.

- More samples about printf command usage in:

[X86-64 processing](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/nasm/sample_64.shtml)

[x32 and below](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/nasm/sample.shtml)